# InfluxDB - Specific data missing from bucket every single time

Tags: database, influxdb, flux, influxdb-2, influxdb-python

I've been following a [very basic tutorial](https://thedatafrog.com/en/articles/docker-influxdb-grafana/) for reading data from a sensor and writing it to a bucket in influxdb. The tutorial is out of date, so I've updated my code to use the new apis and query protocols. However, I'm noticing that everytime I write a record to the database, one very specific entry is always omitted, and never present when I read all the entries back (images below). Specifically, the entry for my record where the "input" is 0.1 is always (literally every single time) dropped when writing to the db. I have no idea why this is happening.

Github Repo: https://github.com/advermaMQ/influx-playground

Details:

I'm running this in Docker as shown in the tutorial, except I'm using the latest version of influxdb:
InfluxDB version: InfluxDB v2.7.1 (git: 407fa62) build_date: 2023-04-28T13:24:27Z

[terminal output of writing entries to db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgfBZ.png)
[terminal output of reading entries from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AtLl.png)
[code that writes entries to db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kTJm.png)
[code that reads entries from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhTHV.png)

I've tried using a new database, opening the UI explorer and inspecting the bucket manually, etc. Nothing seems to fix this. There are other odd behaviors occurring too, but this is the main and worst bug I seem to be facing.